# Laravel, how to save DomDocument to database?

Tags: database, laravel, save, domdocument

I'm stuck with my project and i need your help!
I'm trying to save domdocument variable to my database. 
I'm using **Laravel 5.4**

How do i save the following variable?

```
$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
```

My Controller:

```
TemporaryScan::create([

'title' => ??

]);
```

Temporary scan table:

```
Schema::create('temporary_scans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'm not sure if using text() is the right option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $ts = new TemporaryScan;
 $ts->title = $title;
 $ts->save();
```

or

in TemporaryScan Model

```
protected $fillable = ["title"];
```

in Controller

```
$ts->fill($request->all())->save();


<?php
$xml ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</book>
 <book>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</book>
<book>Clean Code</book>
</books>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
$string = "";
foreach($books as $node)
 {
   $r = $dom->saveXML($node);
   $string .= $r;
 }
echo $string;
?>
```

and save $string;

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've tried this but i get this error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string. How to fix this?

Comment: just edit answer, must DOMNodeList convert to strging,
so `$dom->saveHTML($title)`